# Calculating margin based on screen height

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css

I have an application with some smallish windows that are displayed in isolation - these windows look fine when viewed on a small screen, but on a large one they look awkwardly small (and perhaps more annoyingly, awkwardly positioned).

Is there a way to have, say, a 0px margin-top if the screen height is less than 1000px, then increase that margin-top by 50% of any additional height beyond that?

Most importantly, I only want to consider implementing something like this if it can work dependably cross-browser (some of my users will be as far back as IE7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery/javascript (cross-browser) it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   if(screen.height > 1000)
      $('body').css('margin-top', (screen.height-1000).toString()+'px');
   else
      $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen dimensions using the screen object in js, see http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/screen.htm

anyway, are you really using multiple instances of the browser as 'windows' (using `window.open`)? this will let you run into popup blockers, no?
in case you refer to 'windows' as 'html elements' (such as using a `div` for each 'window') you need to get the dimensions of the browser 'viewport' instead, using jquery this is

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

Comment: I didn't mean separate browser windows as in popups, I more meant certain pages that have small amounts of content.